# Why $\int^1_0|g(t)||e^{-izt}|dt\le e^{|y|}\int^1_0|g(t)|dt?$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be entire function and $z=x+iy\in \mathbb{C}$.
> \begin{align}
> |f(z)|&=\displaystyle|\int^1_0 g(t)e^{-izt}dt|\leq \int^1_0 |g(t)|\cdot|e^{-izt}|dt
> \\ &=\displaystyle \int^1_0|g(t)|e^{yt}dt\leq \int^1_0 |g(t)|e^{|y|t}dt
> \\ &\leq e^{|y|}\int^1_0|g(t)|dt
> \end{align}

Where $g$ is just some continuous function from $[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$.
I am trying to understand where did $|e^{-ixt}|$ gone to? and why can the term $e^{|y|t}$ be taken out of the integral and then the t disappeared? I am baffled by this so much and failed to reproduce this same result. I would just be stuck at $|f(z)|=\displaystyle|\int^1_0 g(t)e^{-izt}dt|\leq \int^1_0 |g(t)|\cdot|e^{-ixt}|\cdot|e^{|yt|}|dt$.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: $|e^{ia}|=1$ if $a$ is real. $e^{|y|t}\leq e^{|y|}$ and the constant $e^{|y|}$ can be taken out of the integral.

Comment: Please clarify the title, as it is not related to the whole problem. Change it to something like "Where did |e^{-ixt}| go in the function..."etc.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks for the comment! I'm still a bit confused on the part $|e^{ia}=1| $ if $a$ is real. Is it because we have $|e^{ia}|=|cos(a)+isin(a)|=\sqrt{cos(a)^2+sin(a)^2}=\sqrt{1}=1$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The $e^{ixt}$ "curve" lives on the unit circle, which implies that $|e^{ixt}| \leq 1$